# Fourier coefficients using matlab numerical integration

Tags: fft, matlab, numerical-integration

I have been trying to display the an and bn fourier coefficients in matlab but no success, I was able to display the a0 because that is not part of the iteration.

I will highly appreciate your help, below is my code

```
syms an;
syms n;
syms t;
y = sym(0);
L = 0.0005; 
inc = 0.00001; % equally sample space of 100 points

an = int(3*t^2*cos(n*pi*t/L),t,-L,L)*(1/L); 
bn = int(3*t^2*sin(n*pi*t/L),t,-L,L)*(1/L); 
a0 = int(3*t^2,t,-L,L)*(1/L); 
a0 = .5 *a0;

a0=a0

for i=1:5 
    y = subs(an, n, i)*cos(i*pi*t/0.0005)
    z = subs(bn, n, i)*sin(i*pi*t/0.0005)  
end
```

Comment: what is the error matlab retrieves?

Comment: and could you provide us with a list of the expected results?

Answer (score 1):

If everything you stated within your question is correct, I would tend to solve it this way:

```
clc, clear all,close all

L = 0.0005;
n = 5;
an = zeros(1,n);
bn = zeros(1,n);

for i = 1:5    
    f1 = @(t) 3.*(t.^2).*cos(i.*pi.*t./L);
    f2 = @(t) 3.*(t.^2).*sin(i.*pi.*t./L);
    an(i) = quad(f1,-L,L).*(1./L);
    bn(i) = quad(f2,-L,L).*(1./L);
    a0 = .5.*quad(@(t) 3.*t.^2,-L,L).*(1./L);
end
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks...that looks like what i needed, the results seems close to what I am expecting, also i edited the original code as i forget to include the equally sample spaces points.

Comment: Expected result: I want to be able to vary the equally sample space and calculate the percentage error values using matlab numerical computation.

Comment: If the answer fulfills your expectations you might consider to prove it as the right one